# Samba: Moving a file inside a share requires read permissions on the target dir

Tags: permissions, samba

I stumbled on something odd. Samba seems to require **read permissions** on the filesystem on a target folder if I want to **move** a file to it (not for copying). This goes across Samba versions (2 tested) and underlying file systems (local filesystem with ext4, nfs mount).

Is there some way to get rid of this restriction?

**Test case:**

Create directory structure as root

```
su - root
mkdir -p /tmp/samba_test/write_only
chmod 777 /tmp/samba_test
chmod 773 /tmp/samba_test/write_only
```

Verify directory structure

```
find /tmp/samba_test -exec ls -ald {} \;
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Dez  9 12:44 /tmp/samba_test
drwxrwx-wx 2 root root 4096 Dez  9 12:17 /tmp/samba_test/write_only
```

Create file as unpriviledged user (access as others)

```
touch /tmp/samba_test/file
find /tmp/samba_test -exec ls -ald {} \;
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Dez  9 13:47 /tmp/samba_test
drwxrwx-wx 2 root root 4096 Dez  9 12:17 /tmp/samba_test/write_only
find: ‘/tmp/samba_test/write_only’: Keine Berechtigung
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 0 Dez  9 13:47 /tmp/samba_test/file
```

move file to write_only

```
mv /tmp/samba_test/file /tmp/samba_test/write_only
 find /tmp/samba_test -exec ls -ald {} \;
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Dez  9 13:49 /tmp/samba_test
drwxrwx-wx 2 root root 4096 Dez  9 13:49 /tmp/samba_test/write_only
find: ‘/tmp/samba_test/write_only’: Keine Berechtigung
```

check that file is there as root

```
find /tmp/samba_test -exec ls -ald {} \;
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Dez  9 13:49 /tmp/samba_test
drwxrwx-wx 2 root root 4096 Dez  9 13:49 /tmp/samba_test/write_only
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 0 Dez  9 13:47 /tmp/samba_test/write_only/file
```

So thats how Linux (the Filesystem ext4?) handles it. Write permissions are enough to move a file to a directory that is only writable but not readable.

Now lets do the same from Samba (Version 4.7.6-Ubuntu, Ubuntu 18.04)!

This is the samba configuration:

```
grep -vE "^([[:blank:]]*[#;]|$)" /etc/samba/smb.conf
[global]
   workgroup = <Our_Active_Directory>
   netbios name = <Our_Server_Hostname>
   security = ADS
   realm = <Our_Kerberos_Realm>
   encrypt passwords = yes
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   dns proxy = no
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   syslog = 0
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes
[samba_test]
        comment = Test
        path = /tmp/samba_test
```

Now access the share in your Windows Explorer, create file2 in your share and try to **move** it to write_only. You'll receive an error that you need permissions for this task (to make changes to file2), those should be granted by . Even `chmod 777 /tmp/samba_test/file2` does not change that.

Copying file2 does work (e.g. hold down CRTL to copy in the Windows Explorer)! (You can verify that it's there on your Linux-Machine)

Same behaviour if I do this with Powershell (Move-Item/Copy-Item).

If you do `chmod o+r /tmp/samba_test/write_only` moving a file there works.

Maybe there is a flag to change Samba's behaviour?

I've tested it with protocol version SMB1, SMB2, SMB3_11 and Samba version 4.7.6/3.6.23

Also tested it in a different environment at home with my raspberry pi.
SMB3_11, Samba 4.9.5. This is a standalone Samba-Server used as network target for my canon printer.

Comment: Is the Samba machine supposed to be a Unix domain member or a standalone server ? it cannot be both and yours is

Comment: Thank you Rowland for pointing that out! I changed the role to "member server", restartet smbd, checked that I have no open connections visible on the server (smbstatus) or the client (net use) - and repeated my test. Changing the role did not affect the behaviour.
Can anyone reproduce this?

Comment: Now that we have found out that it is a Unix domain member, where are your 'idmap config' lines ? Or are you using the totally unsupported sssd ?

Comment: I've just read up a little bit on idmap config in the documentation for smb.conf. The Samba-Server is joined to our Active Directory using ```net ads join```. A subset of our Active Directory users is maintained in NIS, ```/etc/passwd``` runs in compat mode. Usernames match across AD and NIS. idmap config is not configured for us. sssd is not installed.

Comment: Then Samba hasn't got a clue who your users are, you need to add the 'idmap config' lines, remove the users from /etc/passwd and extend the users in AD using ID's from /etc/passwd e.g. if user 'fred' has the Unix ID '1010' then add a uidNumber attribute containing '1010' to Fred's object in AD . You will also need to give Domain Users a gidNumber attribute, you will also need to use the winbind 'ad' backend.

Comment: But the mapping works. smbstatus shows users and groups absolutely correct. I don't think thats the issue. But I can try one thing. Set up a Samba server, that uses only local users/passwords and has absolutely nothing to do with any Active Directory - and try to reproduce the issue there. Did you already try to move a file to a directory that's only writable for you Rowland?

Comment: No, a local Unix user is just that, a local Unix user and has nothing to do with AD, try reading this: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Domain_Member It should help to explain it, it is quite good, but then I am biased, I wrote large chunks of it.

Comment: I did a while ago, but this doesn't match our requirements. You add wins as a source for users, we have to use nis. we don't use wins, too. I'm currently at home and tested the issue on my raspberry pi. Same behaviour, no AD or anything else involved, only local unix users with a standalone samba server. If we do further investigation here, could you please try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: You do not use WINS with AD, WINS was used by NT4-style domains. Whilst you can use a standalone server with AD, it is easier to join the computer to the domain. If you don't join the domain, you have to manage the same usernames in both places, on the standalone server and in AD. Even though you use the same usernames in both places, they will always be different users i.e. the user 'fred' on the standalone server will never be the same user as 'fred' in AD, they will have different SID's. I personally have no interest in trying to reproduce what I perceive to be a borked set up.

Comment: That's why I reproduced it in a different environment, with a setup that's not "borked" on a standalone samba server.. I'll gladly show you it's configuration or try a samba configuration if you propose one on the raspberry pi at home.